# Exporting sqlite2 database to SQL

Tags: sqlite2

Hi I'd like to export data from a sqlite2 database into SQL to import into phpMyAdmin. Thanks.

Comment: Well, mind if you post your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found sqlite2

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-2_8_17.zip

And to export it to SQL you do:

sqlite database.db .dump > output.txt

To stop an error in phpMyAdmin you need to delete the first line: "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"