# Share sqlite2 database with Yii webapp

Tags: yii, sqlite2

Hi I've got a sqlite2 database that is being used by a PHP webapp and I want a Yii webapp to access it. At the moment I copied the db file to a local server and I've changed config/main.php to:

```
        'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/thedatabase.db',
    ),
```

When I run the Gii model generator I get:

```
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT DISTINCT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name<>'sqlite_sequence'
```

BTW I am able to convert the database to SQL using

[Exporting sqlite2 database to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443249/exporting-sqlite2-database-to-sql)

Though I want the database to stay as an sqlite2 database so that the Yii app can access up to date user info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the sqlite2 database by using 'sqlite2:' instead of 'sqlite:'

```
'db2'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite2:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../thedatabase.db',
),
```

I can do queries like this:

```
Yii::app()->db2->createCommand($sql)->queryAll());
```

To stop **Error 500 Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element** 'class'=>'CDbConnection' is required in config/main.php. I think that info is already included in the first database connection somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought it looks like it would be simpler to just use some code from the old PHP project in the Yii project...

```
$db = sqlite_open($databasefilename, 0666, $sqliteerror);
$query = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username='$username'");
$row = sqlite_fetch_array($query);
if ($row) {
    return $row[password];
}
```

Edit:
When using that code I get the following error:
undefined function sqlite_open()

I'm using PHP Version 5.4.7...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php

Here it says:
PHP 5 < 5.4.0